# Return various amounts of values in symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, return

I have little problem, because I have no idea how to do one thing. I want to return on page sometimes 3 values, sometimes 5, sometimes n and I have no idea how to do it. Here is my code (controller):

```
$result = count($countries);
$tablica = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $result; $i++)
{
    $tekst2 = "SELECT nazwa FROM product WHERE id = '$countries[$i]'";
    $id_zap2 = mysql_query($tekst2);
    $tablica[$i]['nazwa'] = mysql_fetch_array($id_zap2);
    $tekst2 = "SELECT jednostka FROM product WHERE id = '$countries[$i]'";
    $id_zap2 = mysql_query($tekst2);
    $tablica[$i]['jednostka'] = mysql_fetch_array($id_zap2);
}
```

I want to return all these $tablica[x]['jednostka'] and $tablica[x]['nazwa']. But I have no idea how I can return it if I use this:

```
return $this->render('MainBundle:Default:addtolist.html.twig', array(
   //What to do here?
));
```

Anybody have idea how I can solve this problem?

I wanted to return something like:

```
"testn0" => $tablica[0]['nazwa'],
"testj0" => $tablica[0]['jednostka'],
"testn1" => $tablica[1]['nazwa'],
"testj1" => $tablica[1]['jednostka'],
...
"testnn" => $tablica[n]['nazwa'],
"testjn" => $tablica[n]['jednostka'],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return this :

```
return $this->render('MainBundle:Default:addtolist.html.twig', array('tablica' => $tablica));
```

Then you can parse it in Twig to do whatever you want to.

Comment: I agree with @Ulti. Furthermore, avoid looping of `mysql_query` if possible. That could easily degrade your performance...

Comment: But as Jovan said, you should work on your queries... Have a look at Doctrine for example, it works great with Symfony2 ;)